# Java Constructor Chaining using this()

Tags: java

if in a constructor chaining scenario, I want to use parameterized `super()` in subclass constructor to call super class' parameterized constructor before `this()` then how to code??
because super class default constructor is automatically called without mentioning `super()` before `this()` in Subclass constructor but if i want to call parameterized constructor giving arguments in `super()` then how ? because explicitly it does not give permission to mention `super()` before `this()`.
please reply, Thanks in advance.

```
class Parent {
```

```html
Parent() {
        System.out.println("Welcome in Parent class'Default Constructor"); 
      } 
      Parent(int x) {
        System.out.println("Welcome in Parent class'Parameterized Constructor"); 
        System.out.println("Your Lucky no.is: "+x); 
      } 
    } 



    class Child extends Parent
    {
      {
        System.out.println("I am in init block.");
       }

    Child()
    { 
       // super(7); ERROR!!
      this(10);
      System.out.println("I am in constructor Child()");

    }

    Child(int x)
    { 
     this(20,30);
     System.out.println("I am in constructor Child(int x)");  


    }
    Child(int x,int y)
    {
     
     System.out.println("I am in constructor Child(int x, int y)");  

    }

    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
    System.out.println("I am in main");
    new Child();
    System.out.println("Again I am in main");

    }



    }

}
```

Comment: Show us some code to illustrate your idea.

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29644586/edit). Don't put code in a comment.

Comment: @ Tichodroma i want to use constructor chaining in Child class that's my need and then to access Parent class parametrized constructor. now what to do????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither implicitly, nor explicitly can a constructor use both `super()` and `this()` call. You can either chain to super class constructor (`super()`), or same class constructor (using `this()`).

So, if you want to call parameterized super class constructor, just do that without any mention of `this()` call. It would work.

Comment: yes u did understand my query. but r u confirmed that both can not be used super() and this() explicitly could u tell me any site link or book where it is mentioned because parent class default constructor is called implicitly before this().

Comment: @VivekSaxena When you don't mention any of them, compiler will add a `super()` call. There won't be any `this()` in that case. And yes, I'm sure about this. You can search this on Java Language Specification.

Comment: @VivekSaxena Well, you can mark the answer as accepted :)

Comment: @VivekSaxena I am talking about accepting the answer. Clicking the green tick mark. That you can do.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below classes

```
public class test2 {
    public static void main(String a[]){
        test1 tst1 = new test1(1,2,3);

    }

public class test1 {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    public test1(){
        System.out.println("am in default const");
    }

    public test1(int a){
        this();
        this.a=a;
        System.out.println("am in one param const");
    }

    public test1(int a,int b){
        this(a);
        this.b=b;
        System.out.println("am in two param const");
    }

    public test1(int a,int b,int c){
        this(a,b);
        this.c=c;
        System.out.println("am in three param const");
    }
```

Comment: What does your code tell us?

Comment: This is a sample, which can assist someone to understand the constructor call, using this.

Comment: Do you mind some explanation?

Comment: Please execute the code, and you should be able to understand from the generated output, still if you want, I can explain.

Comment: Child()                                                                                                          {   // super(7); ERROR cant give permission                                                this(10);                                                                     System.out.println("constructor Child()");                                                              }

Comment: @ Vivek, I suppose you wanted to add a comment to the below answer.

Comment: see in this code i want to call parent class parametrized constructor before this() . means i want to initialize Parent  class using it parameterized constructor before i start my constructor chaining in Child class.

Comment: @saurabh yr code showing only constructor chaining but i want to merge it with inheritance

Answer (score 0):

It is up to you to call the super() from the Child's constructor.
If you will not mention super in child constructor then in that case default constructor of the parent will be called using **super()**. However, if you would like to invoke the parameterized constructor of the parent then use **super(pass parameters matching the signature of parent's constructor)**.

Please refer the following code:

```
class Parent {
  Parent() {
    this(30);
    System.out.println("Welcome in Parent class'Default Constructor"); 
  } 
  Parent(int x) {
    System.out.println("Welcome in Parent class'Parameterized Constructor"); 
    System.out.println("Your Lucky no.is: "+x); 
  } 
}


public class Child extends Parent{


  Child(){
    this(25);
  }

  Child(int x){
    super(x);
  }

  public static void main(String arg[]){
    Child child= new Child();

    Child child1= new Child(20);


  }
}
```

Output:

```
Welcome in Parent class'Parameterized Constructor
Your Lucky no.is: 25
Welcome in Parent class'Parameterized Constructor
Your Lucky no.is: 20
```

Here in the parent constructor you will notice that from default constructor you are calling parameterized constructor. This is possible with the help of **this(30)**.

**Edit:** You cannot use super() and this() simultaneously.

Comment: yr code showing only inheritance but i want constructor chaining when i hv inherited a parent class

Comment: Refer my edited answer.

Comment: but u did not use constructor chaining in Child class that's my need and then to access Parent class parametrized constructor. now what to do????

Comment: Edited the answer. Please note that you cannot use super and this simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks Saint if it is then okkk!!!